# JSON RPC error in eris

Tags: solidity, json-rpc, eris-industries

I have deployed contract successfully. I am getting below error when I pass array from JS to contract function.

```
[JSON RPC 2.0 Error] Message Id: 1, (INTERNAL_ERROR) - Error when transacting: Input out of bounds
[Error: Error when transacting: Input out of bounds]
Error callback from sendTransaction
[Error: Error when transacting: Input out of bounds]
```

Array in JS is

```
 data = ['123','4352','54321','76287'];
```

Array type in solidity is `bytes32`.

I am clueless why I am getting this error.

Comment: Not sure if this is what's causing that error but the values in data don't look like bytes32.